# Why isn't my Contact Form 7 form rendering on the website?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I used the shortcode as prescribed by the plug-in, which is [contact-form-7 id=”601″ title=”Contact form 1″].

Instead of rendering the form, I only see the shortcode in Production. Seems like it should be simple but I can't get the form to render on the site.

Meanwhile, another plug-in, WP Forms, works.

I would like to use Contact Form 7 because it integrates with the WP theme (Folie) I installed.

Comment: Have you tried this echo do_shortcode( ' [contact-form-7 id=”601″ title=”Contact form 1″]' );

Comment: @BrijeshDhanani How do I do this in PHP? Is there a way to do this within WP?

Comment: how are you inserting your shortcode in your page?  Are you using the new WordPress block editor or the classic editor to do this?

Comment: @Aurovrata I used the "codeless editor" that came with the theme. I input the short code as a header or text element. I did notice when I use the classic WordPress editor (HTML), the form does render but not as practical as HTML is not my strong suit.

Comment: so that's the reason...the shortcode needs to be inserted as simple text, most editors do not recognise shortcodes and attempt to change the '[' square brackets into HTML special characters, rendering your shortcode null.

Answer (score 0):

the most likely issue is that you are inserting your shortcode using a page builder/bock editor and not using a shortcode widget to do so.  Hence your page editor is re-formatting the shortcode and rendering it null.

Either insert your shortcode using the HTML editor or contact the help for your page builder/editor on how to insert shortcodes properly.